# How to plot the derivative function from the numerical solution of an ode in Maxima

Tags: plot, ode, maxima, derivative

In Maxima drawdf can be used to plot the numerical solution to a first order differential equation. But how to plot the derivative function? For example, let the differential equation be df(x)/dx=x*f(x) and the initial condition be f(0)=0.2 .

```
load(drawdf);
dydx:x*f;
drawdf(x*f, [x,f], [x,0,1], [f,0,1], show_field=false,  soln_arrows=false, [trajectory_at,0,0.2]);
```

How to plot df(x)/dx?

Comment: You might get more responses to your question if you post it to the Maxima mailing list: maxima-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net

Comment: @RobertDodier, thanks.